# Quickly(!) determine which functions are linear/nonlinear.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Well I know how to test for linearity, and the rules behind that. However for tests I'm always given a question "show the 2 linear functions in the group below", and am expected to answer that near instantaneous.

IE, for the following  3 equations ($y(t)$ output from input $x(t)$)

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt} + ty(t)= x(t)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} + y(t) + 1= x(t)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} + t^2y(t)= x(t)$$

I can immediatelly see that the second is non linear, having a constant term "1". Now I belive if a certain part is non linear, any multiplication/addition in the formula would keep it non linear right? - Does the same hold for linear equations?

if $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are linear, $u(t) + v(t)$ and $u(t)v(t)$ are also linear?

And any multiplication by the running variable will also keep the equation linear?

Comment: Do you know the definition of "linear"?

Comment: In geological time scales, everything you do, however slow it might seem, is done quickly. On the other hand, in terms of Planck time pretty much every notion of time you can even comprehend has orders of magnitude that are hard to imagine.

Comment: The $3$ equations you wrote are all linear differential equations. See why at equation $11$ of this link: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Definitions.aspx